Paradiddle Control
I've been working on one of the rudiments of drumming - paradiddles. Get so fast, and they're regular, but get past that tempo, and they go out of shape and time. What hints can I use to improve?

What reason for the dv? We don't get many drum-related questions, and this one is quite legitimate. Not asking what a paradiddle is, just how to perform them well.

I doubt even whether the dv-er knows what a paradiddle is!!

I didn't vote, but maybe there should be a canonical question on what to practice to play any rudiment faster- or to play faster in general- if there isn't already one.

@Edward - can't find one, yet.

There are many ways to improve "control" over speed, but, above certain speed levels, it mostly depends on the technique(s) you're using. The broad, general advices (as in Edward's answer) are almost always valid, but, in reality, they could also to any drumming aspect, and possibly any high performance and practice related activity. Generally speaking, there are more stick/mallet techniques than there are for most general playing of other instruments, at least considering the relation between speed and efficiency.

This applies to any rudiment:
Practice with a metronome.  This lets you measure your speed and also enforces playing at a consistent tempo.
Practice frequently.  5 minutes a day on paradiddles is more effective than a long session once a week.
You need to practice playing the rudiment cleanly- so, don't set your metronome way too fast and expect to eventually get it.
You also need to practice playing efficiently- at faster tempos, you need to learn to use a small amount of energy from small muscles in the fingers to move the drumsticks.  You also need to work out the coordination of everything so that the entire motion is as smooth as possible.  If you are using, for example, a strict wrist-only stroke, that will severely limit your top speed.
You can practice the component parts of the rudiment.  For a paradiddle, this includes the upstroke (accent immediately after a tap), downstroke (tap immediately after an accent), and diddle.  A standard "bucks" and double stroke roll exercise will cover this.  You can also practice playing the right or left hand in isolation.
You should practice the "open closed open" exercise (audio here), where you start painfully slow, gradually speed up until a maximum speed, then slow back down.  This helps you learn how to adjust your technique to play in the entire range of tempos.

Already use a metronome, can't break through the 'glass ceiling'.

@Tim You should add more details about working with a metronome not helping and hitting a ceiling to your question.

This answer is good enough it doesn’t feel right to add my own but I suggest clarifying the aspects of efficiency and technique. Every time I or one of my students has hit a speed limit, it’s always been technique that is the limitation. That seems to be suggested here but not as clear as I think it should be made.

@ToddWilcox I think you should add your own answer- It's not easy to describe correct technique over text, especially not knowing what the asker is doing wrong.

I’m not a drumming teacher or anything, but I think it might help to make sure that your hands (especially your weak one) keep up. Try to separate it and instead of playing r l r r l r l l play only the three strokes that are in the same hand r - r r l - l l or even 4 strokes in one hand r r r r l l l l. Make sure that in both of your hands this goes effortlessly and consistently.

I'd suggest capitalizing the stickings to reflect the accents in a paradiddle.

The r r r r l l l l exercise will not help much with paradiddles faster than 16ths at ~130bpm or so, because r r r r l l l l encourages technique more like a single stroke roll, whereas fast paradiddles use a distinct double stroke technique.

@Edward My intention behind this was not necessary for this to be directly applicable to the paradiddle motion, but, to get a feeling if your hands keep up with the motion, and maybe understand which hand might need more strength to keep up. So instead of blindly doing paradiddles to the metronome, understand the weak link and focus on strengthening that one.
